Python cmd string with import and if statements throws SyntaxError
A synopsis:
Using python -c <cmd>, I get a SyntaxError when using both an import statement and an if statement. If I only use the import, it's fine. If I only use the if statement, again, it's fine. If I use both, it raises a SyntaxError.
In trying to detect if the version of python being executed is satisfactory (via bash), I came across an oddity that I am trying to understand. The goal: executed a single command in python (python -c ) and receive a pass/fail error code and, ideally, print a useful message. Ultimately, I have figured this out using a ternary statement (minus the message), but I'm still curious about the behavior.
Here is a short reproducer:
$ python -c 'if True: print(3)'
3

$ python -c 'import sys; print(sys.version_info[0])'
3

$ python -c 'import sys; if True: print(3)'
  File "<string>", line 1
    import sys; if True: print(3)
                ^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

A functioning solution:
python -c 'import sys; x = 0 if sys.version_info[:2] >= (3,9) else 1; sys.exit(x)'

It seems like the syntax wouldn't be a problem based on the first example above. But, clearly it is. I haven't had much luck searching for this issue.

Python statements are divided into simple (inherently one-line) and compound (possibly multi-line).  Semicolons can only be used to put multiple simple statments on the same line.  Allowing them to separate compound statments leads to ambiguities - for example, if you could have two ifs on the same line, it would be impossible to tell which one an else on a subsequent line would refer to.
